# Providing SSO support for 3rd party systems in our application without another sign in page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, security, single-sign-on

We have an application which we need to allow users from our customer's systems to be able to sign in without seeing another log in screen.

What is the best way to provide an SSO type experience for our customers? I have tried to research Azure ACS and Windows Identity Framework but they all seem to be based on this idea of a common log in popup/screen which all sites use. Unless there is another aspect to this federated identity system I don't think that will work for us. Basically our customers are education institution which have students who sign in and use their own web applications/portals. These customers purchase access to our application and want their students to be able to click a link from their portal and automatically sign into our system.

From looking around it seems important to know that these systems are running on completely separate domains. For some legacy systems we have asked our customer to provide simple api endpoints for a very custom sso implementation. What I'm looking for is any information about a more standard approach for SSO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our specific needs required us to roll our own SSO type system using some simple secret token handshakes.

Answer (score 1):

[SAML 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) is the standard for single-signon.  Your clients would need to have some authentication mechanism on their sites that can be translated into a SAML call to your application.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is this something that Azure ACS can help with? I'm having a hard time trying to find examples that match our use-case. We can definitely ask our customer to do some dev such as implement a SAML call but I don't know what we need to do on our end to support such a request.

Answer (score 0):

When they sign the student on, they should make a quick call to your application, passing you the username of whoever is logged in. In return, you generate a token, store it in a DB along with the username, and send them the token. They append that token to any link to your app in GET form, and it "uses up" the token (removes it from the DB) but signs them in to that account.

Upon generating the token, you can also remove one "credit" from that applications allowed requests, or whatever else you want to do there.